# How to create dynamic HTML<title> tag based on page name with PHP?

Tags: php, html, url

How would I dynamically change my HTML title tag based on the .php/.html file name? Right now I am using a switch case to try and accomplish this, but I am not sure how to get the page name in order to compare it for each case. Here is my PHP code:

```
$prefix = 'MySiteTitle | ';

switch ($_GET['PHP_SELF']){
case 'www.mysite.php/home':
$pageTitle = 'Home';
}
```

And in my title tag, it goes:

```
<title><?php echo $prefix . $pageTitle ?></title>
```

This has not worked so far, as the $pageTitle variable is empty

Comment: Please explain the file structure and  - i presume the title tag is in some kind of template that is used in multiple pages

Comment: Yes, I have externalized my header so I can simply include it in each page. All of my files, home.php, about.php etc, are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might mean $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and not $_GET['PHP_SELF'] (though you could've named your parameter that). Check that output

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

and make sure that echo matches 'www.mysite.php/home'

```
$prefix = 'MySiteTitle | ';

switch ($_GET['PHP_SELF']){
    case 'www.mysite.php/home':
        $pageTitle = 'Home';
     default:
         $pageTitle ='You are here';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was going for!

Comment: But just to avoid confusion in case this may help anyone else, I should have been using $_SERVER instead of $_GET

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

`$pageTitle = rtrim(basename(__FILE__), '.php');`

But this is not a good idea, if you will most certainly not have a single content on each file.

You should do the assignment by yourself : `$pageTitle = 'Article name';`

**Edit**

With a header :

In the header file, you will have something like this :
`<title>My site | <?= $pageTitle ?></title>`

And on the page visited by the user :

```
$pageTitle = 'My article';

require_once 'header.php';
```

Comment: Is their a way to modify this to make it so that it reads what page the user is on, instead of which page the code is on? When I use this, it displays "MySiteTitle | Header", because I have externalized my header.

Comment: In fact, you should yourself do this assignment. See my updated answer.